# Use map to return nil for an optional value

Tags: swift

I try to write a function as follows:

```
func mapTest(value: Bool?)  {
    var dataTest: String?
    dataTest = value.map({ val in
        if val {
            return ""
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

The Xcode compiler throws an error now at "return nil". Can someone explain me why? my dataTest is an optional String so that it should be able to assign nil to dataTest. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, you want `flatMap` instead of `map`. It behaves in exactly the same way, but it strips optionals out.

```
func mapTest(value: Bool?)  {
    var dataTest: String?
    dataTest = value.flatMap({ val in
        if val {
            return ""
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Also ternary conditional operator could be used `dataTest = value.flatMap { $0 ? "" : nil }`